# Reading Microsoft tags

Tags: c#, tags, microsoft-tag

You guys are probably aware of [Microsoft Tags](http://www.microsoft.com/tag/).

We have a barcode gun in our office and I would like to read these tags using C#.

Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft Tag initiative is based around image recognition, a barcode gun won't have any idea of what to do with a 'Tag', but you can use your phone camera. There's a sample app in the Apple App Store if you have an iPhone, not sure if they've written a version for Windows Mobile yet.

The principle is that you can resolve the tag to a short alpha-numeric code (think GUID but smaller) and then look that up using Microsoft's register of tags, using Web Services.

Comment: comment below...I dont want to use phone. I want to capture events in my code. I guess right question is , is there any API out there ?

Comment: first off you would need an image capture device, web-cam is the easiest, then you would need to 'read' them, I haven't signed up for the developer license, but I'm sure if you do you'll soon find if there's an API for reading/capturing the tags on a desktop PC.

Answer (score 0):

The question is why?

There have been companies spruiking this for years and it just doesn't make sense.

I'd rather have an application that read a URL from a photo, OCR'd it and then punched it into a browser for me.  That way you get the ability to click and view, but you don't need a phone in your hand to write down the URL.  They're all striving for a vendor lock in.

Call me a luddite or blind to the way of the future but I just don't see this as a "killer app".

Comment: well in my case I am looking for a 2d barcode and microsoft tag solves that problem. But it has to be done by barcode gun. May be this can not be used this way.